# Neo4j Path returned with falsely alternating relationship directions in cypher-shell

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Having troubles understanding the relationship direction in returned paths.

I have a graph like this

```
(:START)-[:NEXT]->(:NODE)-[:NEXT]->(:NODE)...
```

Now I am matching all paths starting from the start node in the direction of `:NEXT` up to a length of 10, say. Query looks like

```
MATCH t=((:START)-[:NEXT*..10]->(:NODE))
RETURN t;
```

I am getting output paths with seemingly mixed up `:NEXT` directions like

```
(:START)-[:NEXT]->(:NODE)<-[:NEXT]-(:NODE)-[:NEXT]->(:NODE)<-...
```

and I can't understand where the alternating directions come from.

**EDIT:**
The graph is just a straight line (with one direction). No cycles, no branch-offs. Please replicate the scenario in the shell with the following:

```
CREATE (s:START);
MATCH (s:START) MERGE (s)-[:NEXT]->(a:NODE)-[:NEXT]->(b:NODE)-[:NEXT]->(c:NODE)-[:NEXT]->(d:NODE);
MATCH t=((:START)-[:NEXT*..10]->()) return t;

+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| t                                                                            |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| (:START)-[:NEXT]->(:NODE)                                                    |
| (:START)-[:NEXT]->(:NODE)<-[:NEXT]-(:NODE)                                   |
| (:START)-[:NEXT]->(:NODE)<-[:NEXT]-(:NODE)-[:NEXT]->(:NODE)                  |
| (:START)-[:NEXT]->(:NODE)<-[:NEXT]-(:NODE)-[:NEXT]->(:NODE)<-[:NEXT]-(:NODE) |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

See how in the returned paths, the arrows alternate in direction? That's what is confusing me.

Comment: Please, take a look [here](http://console.neo4j.org/r/2zqmqp) and execute the query. I only edited your query changin `:ST` to `:START` and `:N` to `:NEXT`. I believe these are typo errors. For me the result looks ok, not?

Comment: please see the question above with typos corrected

Comment: I executed your queries step by step again and the results looks ok. Take a look [here](http://console.neo4j.org/r/3p9vpn).

Comment: That's cool. But it still doesn't answer the question why the arrow direction is shown as alternating in cypher-shell

Comment: The  problem really occurs in cypher-shell. I updated my answer and opened a [issue](https://github.com/neo4j/cypher-shell/issues/102) in the Github of cypher-shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From the edit of original question:**

> **EDIT:** The graph is just a straight line (with one direction). No
>   cycles, no branch-offs. Please replicate the scenario in the shell
>   with the following:

Executing the statements in `cypher-shell` the issue really occurs. Seems to me a bug. I searched by this problem in the Github of cypher-shell and found nothing. So I opened an [issue](https://github.com/neo4j/cypher-shell/issues/102).

**EDIT 2:**

[The issue](https://github.com/neo4j/cypher-shell/issues/102) I opened on Github was referenced in this [commit](https://github.com/neo4j/cypher-shell/commit/b97583d20193fdc79b9bf4499b46099072c97a48). Probably this fix will be published in the next release.

**EDIT 3**

Issue closed and fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/neo4j/cypher-shell/commit/b97583d20193fdc79b9bf4499b46099072c97a48).

---

**The original answer is as follow:**

I simulated your scenario here. Look:

The sample data set:

```
CREATE (node1:Node {id:1})
CREATE (node2:Node {id:2})
CREATE (node3:Node {id:3})
CREATE (node4:Node {id:4})
CREATE (node1)-[:NEXT]->(node2)
CREATE (node2)-[:NEXT]->(node3)
CREATE (node3)-[:NEXT]->(node4)
CREATE (node4)-[:NEXT]->(node2)
```

Querying:

```
MATCH t=((:Node {id:1})-[:NEXT*..10]->(:Node {id:4}))
RETURN t;
```

The result:

[image: Result 1]

As you can see (and as described in the question) `(:Node {id:4})-[:NEXT]->(:Node {id:2})` is returned. However this is because the option "Connect result nodes" is enabled in your Neo4j Browser. You can disable it in the Neo4j Browser settings. Look:

[image: Settings]

After disabling "Connect result nodes" and running the query again:

[image: Result 2]

Note the option "Connect result nodes" are only applicable to the graph visualization of the result. That is: the relation between `(:Node {id:4})` and `(:Node {id:2})` don't really exists in the result and are not present if you change your visualization to "Table", "Text" or "Code".

Comment: Thank you for the very elaborate answer! Unfortunately I have to clarify further. There are no directed cycles in my graph. Please see my edit in the original question above